# How can I render more than one flash message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application I want to generate sometimes more than one flash message. I have the following method in my application_helper.rb

```
  def flash_message
    flash.each do |key, msg|
      return render "admin/shared/#{key}", msg: msg 
    end
  end
```

But when I initialize a few flash messages in my controller, it shows only the first. Any ideas?

Edit:

And in my layout I do something like that

```
- unless flash.empty?
   = flash_message
```

Comment: You shouldn't do that way.. if you calling same method again there will be no change right?

Comment: Render flash message directly in the view only.. not from another method

Comment: How you are adding message to flash?

Answer (score 1):

As per your code it will return only fist one of the list..

I think its better to do this in view

### using View:

```
- Ruby Code in View 
%ul#error-msg-list
  flash.each do |key, msg|
    %li.error-message= "<!-- your html --> admin/shared/#{key}" 
  end
```

Or else you can store all the flash messages in another array.. and do your logic at controller level, but this is unnecessary memory cost.

Comment: Thanks for help but when I do this in this way it stills show only one flash... I don't know what is going on.

Comment: How you are showing? Can you update in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your function will return on the first call to `return`.

I guess you're aiming for something like...

```
  def flash_message
    result = ''
    flash.each do |key, msg|
      result += render("admin/shared/#{key}", msg: msg) 
    end
    result
  end
```

But if I'm not mistaken you will also need to pass the arguments to `render` differently. Try:

```
render(partial: "admin/shared/#{key}", locals: { msg: msg })
```

A combined version, with a functional twist using `map` and `join` will look like this:

```
  def flash_message
    flash.map do |key, msg|
      render(partial: "admin/shared/#{key}", locals: { msg: msg })
    end.join('')
  end
```

EDIT:

Here is an example. If your `flash` looks like this:

```
flash = {notice: 'Everything find.', error: 'Ups, my bad: Error'}
```

This code

```
flash.map { |key, str| "<div class='#{key}'>#{str}</div>" }.join('')
```

will give you this

```
"<div class='notice'>Everything find.</div><div class='error'>Ups, my bad: Error</div>"
```

If this only renders one flash message, I assume there is only one message in `flash`. Maybe you've overwritten the first, while setting the latter?

Comment: Thanks for help but when I use this code it still render only first flash.

Comment: @MateuszUrbański: I updated my answer. Please check if you have more than one message in `flash`.

Comment: It still not working. I don't have any idea why is that but thanks for trying to help.